# How does a subquery use the main query columns?

Tags: subquery, where

I'm really confused by this SQL here, it's used in our app but I have no idea how it works. I put it in from examples I found online and it seems to have no issues.

What it's doing is grabbing the latest timestamp of a set. We couldn't use `ORDER BY` as there had to be multiple groupings. The actual query is much larger and this is just a cut down version showing the fundamental selection.

```
select * from table1 as main
WHERE NOT (EXISTS (select * from table1 sub
WHERE sub.datetime > main.datetime));
```

(Live online version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/290cc/2)

What I think should be happening in my mind:

Two identical tables selected, the constraint in the subquery is saying:

> Only select the rows from the subquery which have a date greater than any other row in the main query.

In this case:

- Subquery id:1 has only a smaller than or equal to date value from all rows in the main query so it doesn't get selected.
- Subquery id:2 has a date which is larger than id:1 from the main query selection, so id:2 gets selected once. It is not larger than anything else.
- Subquery id:3 has a date which is larger than both id:1 and id:2 from the main query selection, so it gets selected twice.

So the return from the subquery should be (2, 3, 3). So the main query should do a selection which not exists in that set, which should return id:1, but it returns id:3.

Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are some misunderstandings about what the subquery is doing.

First of all, `EXISTS` works in this case by evaluating the subquery for every row of the main query, and returns `true` if the subquery returns even a single row.

Since you are using `WHERE NOT EXISTS(....)`, what's happening for every row from the main query is the following:

- For `id = 1`: The subquery evaluates if there exists a row in the same table, where the date is greater than the date for `id = 1`. And the results would be ids 2 and 3, hence `EXISTS` evaluates to `true`, and `NOT EXISTS` eliminates this row
- For `id = 2`: Same as before, in this case the subquery would return id 3, hence `EXISTS` evaluates to `true`, and `NOT EXISTS` eliminates this row
- For `id = 3`: There are no other rows in this table that have a date greater than it, so `EXISTS` evaluates to `false`, and `NOT EXISTS` returns `true`, so you get this row as a result

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot. I have an extension I'd like to do to this query then, and with your description and my new understanding it should be easy. If I had a new column 'modifier' which is nullable, and I wanted to choose the latest row (by datetime, as before) which has a concrete 'modifier' value, or the latest null 'modifier' row if no concrete value exists - how would I do this?

To me this should simply be
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b94de/3
Which should return the Y row (id:2), but it doesn't, have I misunderstood again?

Comment: To me the above sqlfiddle says:
Don't select those which has a row in the same table which has a datetime greater than it (as you said before), or those rows which have a null modifier compared to rows of the same table which do have a value for the modifier.

Comment: @Firepanda: Your additional question looks too elaborated for asking in a comment. If you can't figure out the solution on your own, feel free to ask a new question, it's perfectly all right. You can add a link to this question if you think that can help, but please remember that questions still need to stand on their own and not rely on external information, thank you.